# Several functions in one RegionPlot with different grayscale

Tags: plotting, syntax

I try to plot the following, but something seems to be wrong in my code and I can't figure out how to fix it:

```
RegionPlot3D[
  {
   CountRoots[σq33[ω, V1, V2, V3], {ω, 0, Infinity} == 0],
   CountRoots[σq33[ω, V1, V2, V3], {ω, 0, Infinity} == 1], 
   CountRoots[σq33[ω, V1, V2, V3], {ω, 0, Infinity} == 2], 
   CountRoots[σq33[ω, V1, V2, V3], {ω, 0, Infinity} == 3], 
   CountRoots[σq33[ω, V1, V2, V3], {ω, 0, Infinity} == 4]
  },
  {V1, 0, 50}, {V2, 0, 50}, {V3, 0, 100},
  {GrayLevel[i, 0.5], {i, 0, 0.8, 0.2}},
  Mesh -> None, 
  LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 14)
]
```

The number of roots in omega of the function `σq33` depends on the other Variables V1, V2 and V3. I would like to visualize that. The regions where `CountRoots` gives different values should be in different gray levels, all with an opacity of 0.5. I think the problem I have is that I do not know how to use `GrayLevel` to define different shades of gray for the different areas.

And do you have an idea how to define the `CountRoots`-functions all in one, maybe with `Map` or something like that? Here is the `σq33`, in case it is necessary to answer the question:

```
σq33[ω_, V1_, V2_, 
  V3_] = (1/48 (Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2]) (1 + Exp[-V3]) + 
   1/48 (Exp[-(V2 - V1)/2] - Exp[(V2 - V1)/2])/(Exp[(V2 - V1)/2] + 
       Exp[-(V2 - V1)/2]) ((Exp[-V1] - Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3]) - (Exp[-V2] - 
        Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])) + 
   1/8 ((Exp[-V1] - Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3]) + (Exp[-V2] - Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])) (-2 (Exp[-V1] + 
        Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + Exp[-V2] + 
        Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3]) (-Exp[-(V1 + V2)/2 - V3] + 
          Exp[-(V2 + V1)/2])/(Exp[(V2 - V1)/2] + 
          Exp[-(V2 - V1)/2])/(ω^2 + (Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + Exp[-V2] + 
            Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])^2)) + 
   1/2 ((Exp[-V1] - Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3]) - (Exp[-V2] - 
        Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])) (-(Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] - Exp[-V2] - 
         Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3]) (-Exp[-(V1 + V2)/2 - V3] + 
         Exp[-(V2 + V1)/2])/(Exp[(V2 - V1)/2] + 
         Exp[-(V2 - V1)/
           2]) (2 ω^2 - (Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + Exp[-V2] + 
            Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])^2)/((ω^2 + (Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + 
              Exp[-V2] + Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])^2) (4 ω^2 + (Exp[-V1] + 
              Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + Exp[-V2] + Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])^2))) + ((Exp[-V1] - 
        Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3]) + (Exp[-V2] - 
        Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])) ((Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + Exp[-V2] + 
         Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3]) (-Exp[-(V1 + V2)/2 - V3] + 
          Exp[-(V2 + V1)/2])/(Exp[(V2 - V1)/2] + 
          Exp[-(V2 - V1)/
            2]) ((Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + Exp[-V2] + Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])^2 - 
          5 ω^2)/(6 (9 ω^2 + (Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + Exp[-V2] + 
               Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])^2) (ω^2 + (Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + 
               Exp[-V2] + Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])^2)) + (Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] - 
          Exp[-V2] - 
          Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])^2 ((Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + Exp[-V2] + 
           Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3]) (-Exp[-(V1 + V2)/2 - V3] + 
            Exp[-(V2 + V1)/2])/(Exp[(V2 - V1)/2] + 
            Exp[-(V2 - V1)/
              2]) (11 ω^2 - (Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + Exp[-V2] + 
               Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])^2)/(2 (ω^2 + (Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + 
                 Exp[-V2] + Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])^2) (4 ω^2 + (Exp[-V1] + 
                 Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + Exp[-V2] + 
                 Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])^2) (9 ω^2 + (Exp[-V1] + Exp[-V2] Exp[-V3] + 
                 Exp[-V2] + Exp[-V1] Exp[-V3])^2)))))
```

Comment: Please rewrite your question to use a **minimal** example and explain what you're trying to do clearly. Do not just dump your current homework problem...

Comment: @R.M Please excuse my bad english, I have tried to make it clearer now. As for the minimal, I think I really need a rather complicated function to show the problem with the number of roots. I am sorry I do not know where exactly my mistake is.

Comment: Take one of the `RegionPlot3D` documentation examples, and try to build up from there.  (You really *don't* need a complicated example, and once you switch to a simpler example, it'll probably be clearer what's going wrong.)

Comment: @BrettChampion I tried that, but as far as I can tell there is no example with several differently-coloured areas in one plot.

Comment: @belisarius I don't think that this is the problem, cause it is a polynomial in Exp[Vi] for i=1,2,3. `Manipulate[
 CountRoots[\[Sigma]q33[\[Omega], V1, V2, V3], {\[Omega], 0, 
   Infinity}], {V1, 0, 100}, {V2, 0, 100}, {V3, 0, 10000}]` works perfectly.

Comment: Bingo.  If you want one graphic with multiple regions, you're going to have to generate them separately and combine them with `Show`.  (Or do something with `ColorFunction` and `ColorFunctionScaling`, but I'd probably go with `Show`.)

Comment: There are two questions here:(1) Does `RegionPlot3D` accept multiple boolean functions as the first argument? (2) how do you use `GrayLevel` for coloring a region plot? I think the answer to the first question is no: `RegionPlot3D` expects a single function as the first argument (you get error when you use a list of boolean functions). (Btw, `RegionPlot` does accept a list of boolean function). As an alternative, you can use separate region plots and combine them using `Show` or `Overlay`. For the second question, check usage examples of `ColorFunction`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ee[v1_?NumericQ,v2_?NumericQ,v3_?NumericQ]:= CountRoots[σq33[ω,v1,v2,v3],{ω,0,Infinity}];

Show[Table[RegionPlot3D[
   ee[v1, v2, v3] == i, {v1, 0, 50}, {v2, 0, 50}, {v3, 0, 100}, 
   Mesh -> None, LabelStyle -> (FontSize -> 14), 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[ i/10 + 1/10, 3/10]], 
   PlotPoints -> 7, BoundaryStyle -> None], {i, 0, 4}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want a better plot, increment `PlotPoints`, but it is too CPU intensive for my poor machine.

**Edit**

here you have a much better image done by @R.M without specifying `PlotPoints`

[image]

Another one, made by @GustavoBandeira with `PlotPoints->12`

[image]

@cormullion made a fly-around movie of this (too big for uploading here), but here's a still:

[image: still]

Comment: I gave you an upvote, 10U$D for that. :P

Comment: I added the movie still (PlotPoints -> 25) only to give me an excuse to ask "what is this plot showing?". I can't decode the equations  - so what is this showing?

Comment: @cormullion Me neither ... just trying to help. Thanks for your edit!

Comment: It looks like a frozen sea, can you see the big piece of ice floating?

Comment: @GustavoBandeira http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination

Comment: Dude...next time you do this , I'm gonna ban your account.

Comment: @cormullion  Problems like this occur when you are in the middle of a Bachelor thesis in Theoretical chemistry and you don't really know what you are doing - sigma is an expression for nonlinear conductivity in an easy 1D model, and the number of roots in dependance of some coefficients is interesting. Well, kind of. But I made some mistakes in the formula given here, and for the actual thesis I switched to 2D graphics. These examples helped me a lot with GrayLevel though, I did not know the command before.